# Find the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{3} + 2 - \frac{1}{(-e)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the limes of function:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{3} + 2 - \frac{1}{(-e)^n}$$

If I break up the statement I get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{3} = \frac {1}{3}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2 = 2 $$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}-\frac{1}{(-e)^n}  = \infty \lor 0 \lor -1$$

Therefore I get multiple solutions for my equation.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Theta30 Definitely lim ;) and by $\infty \lor 0 \lor -1$ I mean the solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=A,~~\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=B$$ then you are allowed to write and to think about:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}({f(n)+g(n)})=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)+\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n) $$

I added a codes in which we can see the case better:

```
   [> with(plots):
   [> pointplot({seq([n, (1/3)*(-1)^(n^2)+2-1/(-exp(1))^n], n = 0 .. 100)}, color = red);
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer! So I can conclude that my splitting up is not correct... Please would you be so kind to show me how to correctly calculate the limit?

Comment: @mgelius: Just for the first term, think about it when $n$ is faced to even numbers and then is faced to $odd$ numbers. Does $(-1)^4$ mean when $n=2$? Indeed, while working on the real number, the sequence $(-1)^{n^2}$ oscillates between $+1,-1$.

Comment: so the limit of the first term is $-1/3$ and $+1/3$ is this correct?

Comment: @mgelius: Yes, so the whole sequence does not have a limit when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: I finally have a question: Wolfram Alpha states that the limit is $4/3$ ("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28-1%29^{n^2}+%2F+3+%2B+2+-+1%2F%28-e%29^n") However, this cannot be correct, isn`t it?

Comment: @mgelius: The link's written incorrectly. The sequence does not have a limit. Having limit makes it unique.

Comment: Nicely written AND illustrated! +1

Answer (score 3):

No. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^{n^2}$ does not exists as it is an occeleting sequence containing $1$ and $-1$. So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{3} \neq \frac{1}{3}$. As $e  > 1$ $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}e^n  = \infty$ and hence the reciprocal is $0$.

Comment: Therefore the lim of this expression is $7/3$ is this correct?

Comment: @mgelius, I think Samprity's point was that the limit doesn't exist (or else, as the last two addends are converging, so would $(-1)^{n^2}=(-1)^n$)

Comment: @mgelius Sorry for late response. Remember please $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n + b_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n$ holds if all the limit exists. So the limit of the complete expression does not exists.

Comment: Thx for your answer!!! When I put the function is wolframalpha I get the limit $4/3$. Why cannot this be correct?

Comment: I have no idea about wolframalpha. Can you add the link of the answer you get?

Comment: Her is it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28-1%29^n^2+%2F3+%2B+2+-+%281%2F%28-e%29^n%29 hope it works. Basicly I just put limit and the formula in the search box.